# Replace not had css query selector with jQuery methods

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Is it possible to replace `$('div:not(:has(video))')` with `.not` and `.has`?

Comment: Uhm, no, like `$('div').not('video')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the docs you will find the answer to your question:

> queries using :has() cannot take advantage of the performance boost
>   provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll() method. For better
>   performance in modern browsers, use $( "your-pure-css-selector" ).has(
>   selector/DOMElement ) instead.

https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/

> The .not() method will end up providing you with more readable
>   selections than pushing complex selectors or variables into a :not()
>   selector filter. In most cases, it is a better choice.

https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/

Comment: So, is it better to use native css query selectors or jQuery methods?

Comment: @Iulian Onofrei: Considering that there *is no* native CSS equivalent for :has() (which is the whole point of that first quote), I'd say jQuery methods are better.

Comment: @BoltClock, but, there _is_ a CSS equivalent for `:has()`, the CSS selector in the question works.

Comment: @Iulian Onofrei: The :has() that is defined in selectors-4 is not implemented natively anywhere. So no, there is no equivalent - in particular `document.querySelectorAll('div:not(:has(video))')` will not work.

Comment: @BoltClock, I understand, so, how is it implemented then?

Comment: In JavaScript, which is usually not as fast as native code.

Answer (score 0):

How about this? Uses one, but not both:

```
$('div').not(':has(video)')
```